# Adobe air mobile size in percent

Tags: android, ios, actionscript-3, air, screen

I want to create adobe air mobile app for Android and iOS, application is not game and I will use only vectors for GUI. Does it make sense to calculate the size of the objects and text size in percentage for multi screen?

Example header will be height 10%(10% percent convert to pixels) of stage height and width 100%, all objects inside header will be calculated in percent too in relative size to header.

Button in header will be 70% height of header height and so on...

Comment: You should design with physical sizes - control the actual size everything is displayed. So, for example, your header and buttons will be a certain size in inches, not pixels or percentages of the display. Pixel density tells you how many pixels per inch the device's display has. Google's Material Design >  Layout > Units and Measurements is a quick overview on pixel density: http://www.google.com/design/spec/layout/units-measurements.html

Comment: I wan to use percentage of display to avoid DPI calculation because air Capabilites.DPI is not so correct? My application will be always in portrait mode so percentage is very ok?

Comment: With percentage I mean everything position and size too. Percentage of display screen.

Comment: I haven't worked on it recently but yes, devices don't give you DPI. I think you have to figure out what device it is and have the DPIs stored. There may be shared code or an ANE that will do it for you. The problem is the difference in size between a 4 inch and 5.7 inch display is pretty dramatic and 4 inch phones are still used by over 20% of users.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is the safe and faster way (I use this way). But you can put the hardcoded values and multiply the device width divided by the stage width too.

```
    stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;
    stage.align = StageAlign.TOP_LEFT;

    //before set the stage to "fullscreen"
    var ratio:Number = Capabilities.screenResolutionX/stage.stageWidth;

    //resing the stage to the screenResolution
    stage.stageWidth = Capabilities.screenResolutionX;
    stage.stageHeight = Capabilities.screenResolutionY;

    //
    myObject.width = 45 * ratio;
    myObject.height = 50 * ratio;
```

Comment: I think this is not good, my app will be full screen and resolutionX and stageWidth in that sutation will be the same. So that means my myObject will be 45px on all devices?

Comment: Assuming your stageWidth is 640px and your mobile screenResolutionX is equals 720px. Before you set the stageWidth = screenResolutionX, calulate  the ratio (720/640 = 1.125). So 45 * 1.125 = 50.625.